# send textbox variables via php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have created a form using Ninja Forms on my WordPress website. I have one long form, which I've divided into tabs. When the user clicks the first button to continue, I want to send an email with specific fields. The issue is that my variables don't show up in my email. I'm receiving blank emails.

I've tried a number of things including ajax and a separate sendme.php. Since I'm using Wordpress, I decided to use the wp_mail function.

Here's my code. The variables work in my jquery alerts, but still aren't passed to my email.

I included this in my header.

```
$("#cont-btn").on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#ninja_forms_field_30").val(); 
    var company = $("#ninja_forms_field_76").val(); 
    var title = $("#ninja_forms_field_75").val(); 
    var email = $("#ninja_forms_field_33").val(); 
    var phone = $("#ninja_forms_field_32").val(); 

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendme.php",
    data:{ name: name, company: company, title: title, email: email, phone: phone }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
  })
});
```

And this is the basis of my sendme.php

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$to = 'me@email.co';
$subject = 'Enterprise Quote (PT1)';
$message = 'Email: ' .$company ; 

$headers = '';

mail($to, $subject, $message) or die('Error sending Mail'); //This method sends the mail.
?>
```

A few things:

I don't want to validate the form. 
I don't want to submit the form. 
I want the user to stay on page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Afaik you cannot execute php code the way you do. You get blank email because your php script is executed when page is being loaded so there are no variables to pass

Comment: You cannot mix php and javascript like that. You need ajax if you want to submit partial forms and remain on the same page.

Comment: you'll need a separate PHP file and then a callback using javascript. I personally like `$.post` (it's jquery though and sometimes ppl here hate jquery answers)

Comment: @SamCreamer I don't think you need to worry about that, the question is tagged with `jquery` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix PHP and Javascript in this fashion, you have to separate you php and trigger it using AJAX requests.

So first put the php code in a separate file:

send.php

```
<?php 
   $headers = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';

   $message = $_POST['et_contact_message'];
   $message .= '
   Name: ' . $_POST['ninja_forms_field_30'];
   $message .= '
   Company: ' . $_POST['ninja_forms_field_76'];
   $message .= '
   Email: ' . $_POST['ninja_forms_field_33'];
   $message .= '
   Phone: ' .  $_POST['ninja_forms_field_32'];
   wp_mail( 'myemail@company.com', 'Enterprise Get a Quote (PT1)', $message, $headers ); 
?>
```

Then in your JS (jQuery)

```
$("#cont-btn").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $('#the-form').serialize(); //replace 'the-form' with your form id
  $.post('/link/to/send.php', formData, function(res){

  });
});
```

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(data);`?

Comment: I'm not sure where to access that

Comment: The console is in the 'Developer Tools' or inspector. if you are using firefox then right click and then click on 'inspect element' this will toggle the developer tools' then click on console. When you have the console open, try clicking on the 'cont-btn' in the form and see what output you get in the console